# Are Non computer savvy ppl fully protected/anonymous on tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tor-install, pre-tor-proxy, torproject.org

Consider the person whose knowledge of computers goes only as far as their "Computer Class" in highschool, which was really only about Microsoft Office anyways. They pretty much heard about Tor on Youtube, they download the Tor Browser using Chrome, as far as precautionary measures they know to exit Chrome and not use full screen on Tor and tape over their camera, and of course to not use identifiable words such as addresses, emails, names, numbers...etc.

Can that person be comfortable in assuming that their completely Anonymous when, using Tor or is there new steps or programs someone should use with Tor,  or extra precautions they should take. I just cant honestly believe it can just be as simple as using a different browser, at least no stay that simple for long.

Im asking because I know that when talking about the world of Computers, internet, and internet capable devices from a security standpoint, things are always evolving, advancing and changing so what you knew about something a month ago may no longer be the case. For example when cell phones really became advanced, im talking only touch screens from then on out, the app market was starting to grow really fast. Around the time of the iphone 5 put it that way. At that time cheating in a relationship became so so so much easier, the means to do it, the ways to meet people to cheat with were everywhere, but then a shift happened and now its very easy for someone who's not an experienced hacker to catch someone cheating whereas before the apps that provided secrecy and privacy ruled the domain, but then idk I guess the league of estranged relationship partners formed and they took them down one by one lol. Although its gotten a bit harder It is still possible to cheat and leave no tracks im sure but today its a lot easier to get caught then it was.

Sorry for the tangent. Back to my question. If a completely computer illiterate was to ask for a basic list in layman's terms maybe even with links of the steps and processes they should take to stay anonymous. Not like running from the Russian Government anonymous but just to idk order some Cuban Cigars anonymous (if that reference is not aloud I will remove it).

Im seriously hoping someone can make a simple list of numbered steps and then above or below those steps could go into detail (if the want to) why these steps are important, how they've changed, and then if and how the process might changed again, or even if Tor is still the right way to go.

Thanks in advanced for the answers. And I hope you Ladies and Gents are having a wonderful week!

Answer (score 1):

> Can that person be comfortable in assuming that their completely Anonymous when, using Tor or is there new steps or programs someone should use with Tor, or extra precautions they should take. I just cant honestly believe it can just be as simple as using a different browser, at least no stay that simple for long.

No, it's not and the Tor Project *explicitly states* that it is not both on the [download page for Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en#warning) *and* on the about:tor landing page which is the *first thing that you see every time you open Tor Browser.* It states:

> Tor is NOT all you need to browse anonymously! You may need to change some of your browsing habits to ensure your identity stays safe.

The problem is not a technological one, or a technological understanding one. It is behavioural, it *cannot* be fixed by simply adding more technology or gaining more technological understanding. It requires that users *change their behaviour*.